# Does BGP protocol is required to run IS-IS Segment Routing?

Tags: bgp, is-is

In order to do IS-IS segment routing, do I need to run BGP on routers? Lets say, I have R1-R2-R3-R4 topology. In this topology, I will configure IS-IS segment routing on all routers. My question is do I need to configure BGP also on all routers to create the SR tunnel from R1 to R4. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

IS-IS and BGP are seperate routing protocols. IS-IS is commonly used for internal routing (IGP) and BGP for external routing exchange (EGP).

There is no specific requirement to run them in any combination unless you build your network in that way.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I understand that we don't need BGP protocol to run IS-IS. However, do we need BGP to configure IS-IS segment routing tunnel?